# SSRS 2012 Active Directory Group Not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I added a group I created in AD and gave access to a folder in SSRS. When I add a user to the group user can't see folder in SSRS. When I add domain user group to folder, user can see folder.

Seems like a caching issue. I tried to reboot service, but that did not work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem that I ran into once when first setting up a report server. Without the parent having permissions, when users navigate to ReportServer/Reports/, the sub-folders will not appear.

Give Browser permissions for the AD Group on the Parent Folder

ReportServer/Reports/ <-- Home (Needs Browse Permission)

ReportServer/Reports/Your Folder <-- Your Folder Name (Already has Permission as stated in OQ).

To give browser permission to the Home folder, Click "Folder Settings" when at the Home directory. Any sub-folders that the group does not have permission for will still appear but are inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by just logging off and logging back on. Drove me nuts.